# Ubuntu server 16.04.4 hangs on reboot but not poweroff

Tags: 16.04, server, systemd, reboot

After a fresh install of Ubuntu server 16.04.4, the system shuts down fine with `sudo poweroff` but hangs completely after : `sudo reboot`, `sudo systemctl reboot` or `sudo shutdown -r now`. It doesn't matter if the command is launched via SSH or local session.

I tried to add `acpi=force` as GRUB option, I tried to disable the swap but nothing worked so far.

Here's the displayed message as a picture. I think it happens too late during the process and isn't logged anywhere :

[image]

Possibly relevant lines could be :

```
systemd-shutdown[11]: failed to finalize DM devices, ignoring
...
general protection fault: 0000 [#11] SMP
...
Code: Bad RIP value.
...
```

Do you have any idea what the problem is or what a possible fix could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to experiencing a kernel bug or hardware failure, since you triggered a general protection fault.

This is likely hardware-specific.

I would recommend trying to upgrade to an 18.04 beta, since 18.04 is nearing release, and seeing if the newer kernel fixes it.

Otherwise, consider searching for a kernel bug report about that relates to your hardware. If none is found, considering opening a new kernel bug report about it.

Comment: I thought about updating to 18.04, yes, and will try it ASAP. I don't think I should try it over SSH though, since I'll have to reboot at least once with the current kernel. It seems weird to me that `poweroff` works but `reboot` doesn't. I'll come back to comment.

Comment: Upgrading to 18.04 solved the reboot problem. Thanks.